# Does solidity have a method like range() to generate numbers within the range like [1:5] -> [1,2,3,4,5]? Or need to use for loop?

Tags: solidity, arrays

I'm new to Solidity.

Does solidity have a method like range() to generate numbers within the range like [1:5] -> [1,2,3,4,5]? Or need to use for loop?

For example, a = list(range(1,21)) is what I used to do with Python,
In Solidity,
uint[20] SampleArray;
SampleArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];
this or need to use for loop by pushing numbers in a dynamic array would be the way? Would there be more simple way?

Also, I still don't get why people declare the value first and then assign later in Solidity.

Answer (score 0):

No solidity does not have pre-defined functions such as range() which is present in python. To generate range, you have to use a for loop and push the data one by one to the array.

For your last line question, could you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

My friend gave me a great answer for this.

- there's no function like that but on the low level that's no different than using a loop.
- can push numbers in a dynamic array in a for loop but if we know how many entries, have unrolling the loop / hard coding each one and that will be cheaper

and for my last line, it was not Solidity what I saw Sorry for the confusion